# Plot Multiple bar plots

Tags: python, seaborn

Hello I am trying to plot multiple bar plots, but something went work and getting wrong plots, Here are the codes:

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(15,16)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 3)

for i in range(len(data.columns)- 1):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            sns.barplot(y = data.iloc[: , i], x = data.quality, ax = axes[j][k])
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is bothering you? Is it the fact that you get the exact same plot in all 9 subfigures?

Comment: Yes. All of the plots are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the outer loop is through columns and inner loops through axes, when you go the barplot line, the loops occuring at j & k without going to outer loop, so you are plotting the same column at different axes.

Some thing like this should work :

First create axes list and then loop through columns and the axes list at the same time

```
l = [(j,k) for j in range(3) for k in range(3)]

for i,q in zip(range(len(data.columns)- 1),l):
    sns.barplot(y = data.iloc[: , i], x = data.quality, ax = axes[q[0]][q[1]])
```